# После удаления gtk, Линукс не загружается

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gtk

При установке VMware терминал ругался, что установлены две версии gtk. Почему то оказалось, что у меня стоят и 2.0 и 3.0 версии. Решил удалить обе и поставить заново последнюю версию. Удалил, сделал ребут, и всё. Появляется логотип Linux mint и бегают точки бесконечно. Запускался через терминал, писал `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^`. Десктоп загрузился, однако, зайти на него могу только, если запускают через терминал и ввожу `startx`. Если сделать ребут, появляется логотип загрузки и бегают точки бесконечно.

Comment: Открывать консоль, читать в логах удалённые пакеты и устанавливать пакеты обратно. От gtk2 и gtk3 зависит ВООБЩЕ ВСЯ графика среднестатистического ubuntu-based дистрибутива, они должны стоять оба. Удалив их, вы удалили почти всю систему

Comment: И да, что значит «Не помогло»?

Comment: Десктоп запускается, если в терминале написать startx, но если сделать ребут, появляется логотип загрузки и бегают точки бесконечно

Comment: Жмите Esc и читайте логи. Да и вообще читайте и лог-файлы тоже

Comment: Когда удаляете любой пакет через что угодно - будь то апт, синаптик или любой другой менеджер, вам всегда показывается список зависимостей, которые будут затронуты (если они конечно есть). Эту инфу нельзя игнорировать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему. У меня по умолчанию стоял диспетчер дисплея lightdm, изменил на gdm3 и всё заработало нормально.